# Android Google TTS: Why langAvailable returns Not supported or -2?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, google-text-to-speech

I am following https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/speech/ and getting a single value (Default) in langAvailable.
I have updated Google TTS engine also and installed some voice data. I have installed other app which uses this engine and this apps have all languages.
So what I am doing wrong? Android OS 6.0

```
 TextToSpeech textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this, "com.google.android.tts");
        var langAvailable = new List<string> { "Default" };
        var localesAvailable = Locale.GetAvailableLocales().ToList();

        foreach (var locale in localesAvailable)
        {
            LanguageAvailableResult res = textToSpeech.IsLanguageAvailable(locale);
            switch (res)
            {
                case LanguageAvailableResult.Available:
                    langAvailable.Add(locale.DisplayLanguage);
                    break;
                case LanguageAvailableResult.CountryAvailable:
                    langAvailable.Add(locale.DisplayLanguage);
                    break;
                case LanguageAvailableResult.CountryVarAvailable:
                    langAvailable.Add(locale.DisplayLanguage);
                    break;
            }
        }
        langAvailable = langAvailable.OrderBy(t => t).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Please post your complete error log.

Comment: There is no error. var localesAvailable = Java.Util.Locale.GetAvailableLocales().ToList(); giving some locales but at  LanguageAvailableResult res = textToSpeech.IsLanguageAvailable(locale); this stages all are showing Not supported

Comment: When you deploy the application in you device you cant use the `TextToSpeech` function ? Or you cant compile the project?

Comment: Project is successfully complied and I can debug it also. but at every time LanguageAvailableResult is Not supported for each locale

Comment: What's you mean ''Not supported"? Please describe your problem in detail please, I   don't get what you mean.

Comment: Please find two links **1)** https://www.dropbox.com/s/1f8os9t1jtfctl0/NotSupported.png?dl=0  **2)**  https://www.dropbox.com/s/k5ym02qviff3svu/TTSobj.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Android Google TTS: Why langAvailable returns Not supported or -2?

It seems like Google TTS needs a bit to initialize, you should use `IsLanguageAvailable()` method when  the TTS Engine has initialized correctly.

**For example :**

```
void TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener.OnInit(OperationResult status)
    {
        // if we get an error, default to the default language
        if (status == OperationResult.Error)
            textToSpeech.SetLanguage(Java.Util.Locale.Default);
        // if the listener is ok, set the lang
        if (status == OperationResult.Success)
        {
            langAvailable = new List<string> { "Default" };
            localesAvailable = Java.Util.Locale.GetAvailableLocales().ToList();

            foreach (var locale in localesAvailable)
            {
                LanguageAvailableResult res = textToSpeech.IsLanguageAvailable(locale);

                switch (res)
                {
                    case LanguageAvailableResult.Available:
                        langAvailable.Add(locale.DisplayLanguage);
                        break;
                    case LanguageAvailableResult.CountryAvailable:
                        langAvailable.Add(locale.DisplayLanguage);
                        break;
                    case LanguageAvailableResult.CountryVarAvailable:
                        langAvailable.Add(locale.DisplayLanguage);
                        break;
                }
            }

            langAvailable = langAvailable.OrderBy(t => t).Distinct().ToList();

            var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, langAvailable);
            spinLanguages.Adapter = adapter;

            textToSpeech.SetLanguage(lang);
        }
    }
```

Then, when you select a language from `Spinner` :

```
spinLanguages.ItemSelected += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) =>
{
     lang = Java.Util.Locale.GetAvailableLocales().FirstOrDefault(t => t.DisplayLanguage == langAvailable[(int)e.Id]);
     textToSpeech.SetLanguage(lang);
};
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urJ45.gif).

Comment: I had already solved the issue with same approach. Thanks for follow up and help. Marked as answer. but given Github project has that event in oncreate so I have added there.